# File Upload script not working

Tags: php, html, post, file-upload, undefined

I have this HTML code for posting a file to my upload script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>CONTISEC PORTAL - NEW USER</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="buttcss/gstyle_buttons.css" type="text/css"  media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="usercon.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">



        <p>CREATE NEW CLIENT USER ACCOUNT BY ENTERTING CLIENT REFERENCE NUMBER (supplied by Pershing) AND DESIRED USERNAME.</p>





        <div id="contact-area">

            <form method="post" action="fileproc.php">
                <enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="client_ref">BROWSE:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <label for="client_ref">SELECT FILE:</label>
                <select name="file"> 
                <option value="assets" >ASSETS (DAILY)</option>
                <option value="stock_names" >STOCK_NAMES (DAILY)</option>
                <option value="client_names" >CLIENT_NAMES</option>
                </select>

                <div class="buttons">

                <button class="action redbtn" type="submit"><span class="label">SUBMIT</span></button>
            </form>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>



        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my upload script (from w3 schools):

```
<?php


if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }




?>
```

However, when the page loads, it displays the "Undefined Index" error.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: `enctype` should be an attribute of the `<form>` element, not an element on its own. Also, your select element and your file input both have `name='file'`, so the `<select>` will overwrite the metadata for the uploaded file. Also http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @DaveRamdom look a bit closer. It's right under the label BROWSE:

Comment: @krike Yes I spotted it after I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your form open tag. It is required for uploading files

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam You have the same name for the file select field and the select field this must be causing the problem.
`<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />`

`<select name="file">`